# Register with Autofac a DbContext which uses IDesignTimeDbContextFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, autofac

I want to register OrderContext with Autofac, but OrderContext uses IDesignTimeDbContextFactory and Autofac fails in execution. The error is the next:

> Cannot resolve parameter
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[...OrderContext]
>   options' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[...OrderContext])'.
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)    at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)

Autofac configuration:

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<OrderContext>()
        .InstancePerDependency();
}
```

OrderContext is the next:

```
public class OrderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; }

    public OrderContext(DbContextOptions<OrderContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}

public class OrderContextDesignFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<OrderContext>
{
    public OrderContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<OrderContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(
                "...");

        return new OrderContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share how you register your `OrderContext` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I have edited the post.

Comment: You want *Autofac* to use your `OrderContextDesignFactory` to create `OrderContext` ? The registration you use, don't let *Autofac* knows anything about that. In your factory what is `args` used for ? how *Autofac* is supposed to know about this ?

Comment: `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is for EF tools like Add-Migration, Update-Database etc. command. It isn't (and shouldn't be) used for runtime configuration.